# iOS - Animating UISearchController's search bar

Tags: ios, animation, uisearchbar, uiviewanimation, uisearchcontroller

Just wondering if there was any way to animate the search controller search bar?  I have it set as the titleView to my view controller's navigation item, and it only appears when you click a button.  I would love for it to start from the right side and slide open towards the left to fill the available space, and then when closed slide closed toward the right.  It seems very difficult to modify the search bar though through standard methods - any good techniques for this?